# I've found many questions on abstract classes and interfaces but answer me this: Can an abstract class do everything an interface can?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I'm really confused, and I've read a TON of questions on this topic and I have not been able to pinpoint anything specifically that an interface can do that an abstract class cannot do.

Is there anything an interface can do that an abstract class cannot do?

I am asking in the context of my Java class, but feel free to remove the java tag if it applies to other languages as well (possibly C#?).

Edit: I understand that an abstract class can do things an interface cannot, but if an abstract class can do everything an interface can do, then what is the point of an interface? What does "implement multiple interfaces" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't inherit from multiple abstract classes in c#, but you can implement multiple interfaces.

I think this may apply to java too

Edit:

You can't inherit from multiple classes. If you have an abstract class called Clonable, and an abstract class called Disposable then you can only inherit one of these classes and you're forced to make a decision about which class your class should be a subtype of:

e.g:

```
    public abstract class Clonable
    {
        public abstract void Clone();
    }

    public abstract class Disposable
    {
        public abstract void Dispose();
    }

    // MyClass cannot be Disposable too, it is not allowed by the language

    public class MyClass : Clonable
    {
        override void Clone()
        {

        }
    }
```

Note it is a design decision of the language to allow you only to inherit from one class.

If on the other hand you have interfaces, the language allows you to implement both

e.g.

```
    public interface IClonable
    {
        void Clone();
    }

    public interface IDisposable
    {
        void Dispose();
    }

    public class MyClass : IClonable, IDisposable
    {
        void IClonable.Clone()
        {

        }
        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: How would I inherit from multiple classes? Can you provide a code example? What do you mean: implement multiple interfaces?

Comment: I've edited my response. I can only really give you a code example in c#, maybe someone can give the equivalent in java if it helps

Comment: thanks man, this totally clears it up for me and you are correct, as it turns out I do C# at work and Java for class so your answer is superb. Also in another answer's comment Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen posted a link to the Java explanation: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Twowaysthataclasscanimplementmultipleinterfaces.htm

Answer (score 8):

Interfaces as such cannot do what abstract classes do.

This is because abstract classes can contain code - interfaces cannot.  But any given class can only have *one* superclass - `extends` - as opposed to any number of interfaces - `implements`, so if you use abstract classes you essentially paint yourself in a corner of the inheritance tree, because your class can only extend a single class.

This limitation does not apply to interfaces, allowing a single class to have many purposes depending on how many interfaces it implements.

Comment: +1 for the line "so if you use abstract classes you essentially paint yourself in a corner of the inheritance tree". nice. :)

Comment: What do you mean it can only extend a single class? If I have an abstract class with no code, how is that different from an interface? Perhaps a code sample would help?

Comment: @Ryan, they are very close.  The question is what you can use that class FOR - an abstract class MUST be subclassed to be useful.  THAT class can only have a single abstract class as ancestor.

Comment: "Implement multiple interfaces" -> "class X implements A,B".  See http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Twowaysthataclasscanimplementmultipleinterfaces.htm

Answer (score 2):

Well read:

- http://mindprod.com/jgloss/interface.html
- http://mindprod.com/jgloss/interfacevsabstract.html

> What does "implement multiple interfaces" mean?

Consider:

```
public static interface Ifun extends Comparable<Ifun>, Serializable {}//or 
public static class Cfun2 implements Comparable<Cfun>, Serializable
```

When class implements `Ifun`, then:

- Comparable interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. Objects that implement this interface can be sorted automatically by `Collections.sort`.
- The serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only to identify the semantics of being serializable.

It means object can have more then 1 interface.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are non instantiable classes that only contains methods that subclasses can inherit. The only thing that interfaces can do (in java) is that a class can implement many interfaces while a class can only extend 1 abstract class.

Comment: interfaces can also be used in proxies, abstract classes can't. This is used all over the place in various frameworks.

Comment: You can't @Ryan, but you can declare a constructor in an abstract class but never in an interface.